# Can't seem to get test coverage for a setTimeout action dispatched inside of an useEffect

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, enzyme, react-testing-library, istanbul

I'm having an issue getting test coverage for a react action dispatch with `window.setTimeout()` the test passes with `done()` but it doesn't actually provide any coverage for the istanbul coverage. I tried a few things but nothing has worked so far. Anyone familiar with testing this? I've also tried using lolex instead to mock the time instead of using `window.setTimeout()` but it fails saying `getBrSeoData` was never called.

This is my code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!Config.ui.isBot) {
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        getBrSeoData(productType, productId, productName, productStatus);
      }, BR_DELAY);
    }
  }, [getBrSeoData, productType, productId, productName, productStatus]);
```

This is the test

```
  it("should make the blooomreach api call if !Config.ui.isBot", done => {
    const BR_DELAY = 6000;
    const response = {
      status: "SUCCESS",
      payload: {
        "related-item": bloomreachState["related-item"],
        "related-category": [],
        "more-results": []
      }
    };
    props = {
      relatedSearches: bloomreachState["related-item"],
      relatedCategories: bloomreachState["related-category"],
      relatedProducts: bloomreachState["more-results"],
      getBrSeoData: sinon.spy(() => new Promise(resolve => resolve({ response })))
    };
    Config.ui.isBot = false;
    component = render(<BloomreachSeo {...props} />);
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      expect(props.getBrSeoData).to.have.been.calledOnce;
    }, BR_DELAY);
    done();
  });
```

Istanbul showing no coverage for the line

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by using the npm package lolex. If anyone has issues with it using react testing library along with testing a `window.setTimeout()`

```
  let clock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    clock = lolex.install({ now: 4476701471000, toFake: ["setTimeout"] });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    clock.uninstall();
  });

  it("should make the bloomreach api call if !Config.ui.isBot", () => {
    const BR_DELAY = 5000;
    const response = {
      status: "SUCCESS",
      payload: {
        "related-item": bloomreachState["related-item"],
        "related-category": [],
        "more-results": []
      }
    };
    props = {
      relatedSearches: bloomreachState["related-item"],
      relatedCategories: bloomreachState["related-category"],
      relatedProducts: bloomreachState["more-results"],
      getBrSeoData: sinon.spy(() => new Promise(resolve => resolve({ response })))
    };
    Config.ui.isBot = false;
    component = render(<BloomreachSeo {...props} />);
    clock.tick(BR_DELAY);
    clock.setTimeout(() => {
      expect(props.getBrSeoData).to.have.been.called;
    }, BR_DELAY);
  });
```